# How to pass a Redux action into 2 reducers to update state in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, reducers

My app has a clickable item in `CurrentStatus` component that passes a `service.id` to the parent component `Dashboard` and gets `service_notes` via a Redux action with `axios.get`. `service_notes` are passed into a reducer and into the Redux store. I then `connect` to the store in `ServiceLogs` component and iterate through the array to display in `render()` on the DOM. `ServiceLogs` is a comments type component where a user can add notes. I'm able to create the notes but can't update the state. My latest approach was taking the `CREATE_NOTE` action and using it in `notesReducer` AND `serviceNotesReducer`. This still doesn't update state and the DOM.

Here is my layout:

[image: Dashboard_wirefram]

Here are the relevant components:

Dashboard:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Container, Grid, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import CurrentStatus from "./components/CurrentStatusComponent";
import KnownOutages from "./components/KnownOutagesComponent";
import ServiceLogs from "./components/ServiceLogsComponent";
import { getServices } from "./actions/getServicesAction";
import { getServiceNotes } from "./actions/getServiceNotesAction";
import { getOutages } from "./actions/getOutagesAction";


class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {
        serviceNotes: null,
        serviceOutages: null,
        showServiceLogs: "none",
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getServices();
    this.props.getOutages();
  }

  displayServiceLogs = serviceId => {
    debugger 
    this.props.getServiceNotes(serviceId)
     this.setState({ showServiceLogs: "none" ? "block" : "none"}); 
  }

  render() {
      console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid>
          <h1>TML Dashboard</h1>
        </Container>

        <Grid columns={3} divided>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={5}>Service Log</Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={6}>Current Status</Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={3}>Known Outages</Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={5}>
              <ServiceLogs showServiceLogs={this.state.showServiceLogs}/>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={6}>
              <CurrentStatus displayServiceLogs={this.displayServiceLogs}/>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column width={3}>
              <KnownOutages />
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        services: state.services.services,
        notes: state.notes.notes  
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
    getServices: () => dispatch(getServices()),
    getNotes: () => dispatch(getNotes()),
    getOutages: () => dispatch(getOutages()),
    getServiceNotes: serviceId => dispatch(getServiceNotes(serviceId))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Here is the `CurrentStatus` component where I click on an item (service) and pass the id up to Dashboard to `get` from in `getServiceNotes(serviceId)` function in `getServiceNotesActoin`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Table, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4")

class CurrentStatus extends Component {

  handleClick = serviceId => {
    this.props.displayServiceLogs(serviceId)
  }

    render() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this.props.services))
        return (
          <>
            <Table celled padded>
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.HeaderCell singleLine>Service</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Status</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Reason</Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Header>
              <Table.Body>
                {Object.assign(this.props.services).map((service) => (
                  <Table.Row key={uuidv4()}>
                    <Table.Cell
                      onClick={() => this.handleClick(service.id)}
                    >
                      <Header as="h3" textAlign="center">
                        {service.name}
                      </Header>
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell textAlign="center">
                      {service.is_down ? (
                        <h4 style={{ color: "red" }}>Down</h4>
                      ) : (
                        <h4 style={{ color: "green" }}>Up</h4>
                      )}
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell></Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                ))}
              </Table.Body>
            </Table>
          </>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
      services: state.services.services 
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CurrentStatus);
```

and here is the `ServiceLogs` component where I'm able to display and show the related `serviceNotes`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Comment, Container, Grid, Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { createNote } from "../actions/createNoteAction";
class ServiceLogsComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        entry: ""
    }


    handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const userId = 2
        const serviceId = this.props.serviceNotes[0].service.id 
        this.props.createNote(this.state.entry, serviceId, userId)
    }

    render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <>
        <div style={{ display: this.props.showServiceLogs }}>
          <Comment>
            <Comment.Group>
              {this.props.serviceNotes.map((serviceNote) => (
                <Comment.Content>
                  <Comment.Author as="a">{serviceNote.created_at}</Comment.Author>
                  <Comment.Metadata>{serviceNote.user.username}</Comment.Metadata>
                  <Comment.Text>{serviceNote.entry}</Comment.Text>
                </Comment.Content>
              ))}
              <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                <Form.TextArea
                  style={{ height: "50px" }}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  name="entry"
                />
                <Form.Button
                  type="submit"
                  content="Add Note"
                  labelPosition="left"
                  icon="edit"
                  primary
                />
              </Form>
            </Comment.Group>
          </Comment>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    services: state.services.services,
    notes: state.notes.notes,
    serviceNotes: state.serviceNotes.serviceNotes
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
       createNote: (entry, serviceId, userId) => dispatch(createNote(entry, serviceId, userId)) 

    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ServiceLogsComponent);
```

So I cannot updated the DOM when I create a new note. I tried this in these 2 reducers:

```
const initialState = {
  notes: [],
};

export const notesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_NOTES":
      return { ...state, notes: action.payload };
    case "CREATE_NOTE":
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [...state.notes, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and

```
const initialState = {
  serviceNotes: [],
};

export const serviceNotesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_SERVICE_NOTES":
      return { ...state, serviceNotes: action.payload };
    case "CREATE_SERVICE":
        return { ...state, serviceNotes: [ ...state.serviceNotes, action.payload] }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Hope this is clear enough. In short: I need `ServiceLogs` state to change on CRUD action.

Comment: show the code of actions `createNote` , `getServiceNotes` and 'createService`(i.e. the code for CREATE_SERVICE)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should follow the recommendations of the Redux Style Guide: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide
I guess the idea is to keep just one store for the entire app and you should wrap the connection to the store in a higher level (componently speaking) using the  component.

[image]

I would also recommend for you to use the new Redux Hooks like `useSelector` and convert your class components to use React Hooks to simplify your code.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html